# Switching door hinges to other side

Tags: doors, hinges

[image]I'd like to reposition my door/hinges so it opens from the other side (and swings in the opposite direction).

Is it just a matter of installing hinges on the opposite side of the door frame and re-installing?

Thank you for any advice!

Nicole

Comment: Is there no latch? Perhaps a picture might help.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you going from a door that hinges on (say) the left and opens away from you to a door that hinges on the right and opens toward you? Is this an interior or exterior door?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is an interior door. To phrase my question another way, is the knob staying on the same side when the door swings the other way?

Answer (score 4):

Several things to check:

1. Do you have sufficient frame depth on the other side to install a door there?  As you can see, the door currently closes against a thin strip of wood along the top and vertical sides of the frame. You need just as much depth on the far side as the door thickness to be able to mount there.
2. Draw a picture for yourself of how the hinges must mount for whichever way the door is going to swing on the far side. You may have to chisel out new hinge recesses along the door edge -- and of course in any case have to chisel recesses in the far side of the door frame, along with a new recess for the latch mechanism.
3. If this door has a locking knob, make sure you can fully reverse it (or not, depending on which side you want to lock).

And finally, for aesthetic reasons, you'll have to do some patching/ filling of the latch and hinge recesses in the door frame on the current side.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't seem like a big job until you start listing all the little things that have to be done. Buying a new pre-hung door might be the better move unless you're skilled in woodworking (or intend to become so).

Comment: I had this exact situation, but with a pre-hung door.  In my case, I just took out the whole door and put in an identical one that swung the other way.

Comment: This depends on the specifics of the change and the surroundings, but I'd be tempted to think seriously about pulling the trim on both sides/ cutting the entire door unit out/ spinning it 180/ reinstalling/ re-trimming. Less patching, mortising; more paint and caulk. Of course, if this an exterior door, this wouldn't be a viable option because of the threshold configuration.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate In fact, pulling the entire door *frame* , if possible, would be ideal.  (But given your username,  I'm surprised you care about doors :-) )

Comment: @CarlWitthoft -- I love all the openings equally. On the day I picked a username, I had to decide who my favorite child was, and windows won. (That may have corresponded with a door screwup that obliged the purchase of an $800 mortise lock...)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've attached a picture to my original post. 

I do have sufficient frame depth on the other side to install a door. What I didn't think of before is switching the latch to the other side. The hinges seem relatively easy compared to that.